# Script hanging on time.sleep()

Tags: python, sleep

I have a script started with `nohup python3 script.py &` . It looks something like this:

```
import thing
import anotherthing

logfile = "logfile {}".format(datetime.datetime.today())

while True:
    try:
        logging.debug("Started loop.")
        do_some_stuff()
        logging.debug("Stuff was done.")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception("message")

    logging.debug("Starting sleep.")
    time.sleep(60)
```

This works fine, however it seems to hang up on `time.sleep()` (as in it just stops doing anything without killing the process) after about 2 days. According to logs, all parts of the script execute fine, but it always hangs up on the sleep part and doesn't start back. I checked for memory leaks, i/o hangups and connection timeouts, and none of those seem to be the case.

What could be the cause of that behavior and why?

EDIT: Added logging to pinpoint the cause. Logs always finish on `DEBUG    Starting Sleep`.

Comment: Why are not doubting the problem is not in `do_some_stuff()` ?

Comment: can you show `do_some_stuff()` code

Comment: I am not doubting the do_some_stuff() part because according to logs, all of it is successful. It starts with:
`09-03-19 14:50:31  DEBUG    Loop started.`
and ends with 
`09-03-19 14:50:32  DEBUG    Sleep started.`

Logs always hang up on the `Sleep Started` log.

Comment: Add `print("going to sleep")` right before the sleep call and check if it gets there.

Comment: @Keldorn As i said, logs do exactly that. There is a debug log right before `time.sleep()`, and it always gets there and that's the last part of logs.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Still not complete, minimal or verifiable. `do_some_stuff()` undefined, does the code work without it? `logfile` unused. Also, does it work without the `nohup` part?

Comment: yes, works the same if i start it in tmux, or in normal terminal. But as i said, the code in `do_some_stuff` always succeeds (Except when it throws an error, but it's handled by the `try` `except` part. It always gets to the part with `time.sleep(60)`

Comment: Run another version of the script where the implementation of do_some_stuff  is just `pass`. Do you still face those issues?

Comment: I did something similar, just ran `print(datetime.datetime.today())` instead of `pass`. Problem still persisted.

Comment: [Edit] your Question and explain in detail the meaning of *"seems to hang up"*, also verify, if any, the content of the `nohup.out` file. If the script *crashes* you can't trust `logging`.

Comment: Script does not crash, it seems to straight up *hang up* as in just stops doing anything. I suspected crashing, but it's still working (showing up in `ps -aux`). I put it in systemd service and launched it that way with `RestartSec=5` and `Restart=on-failure` to restart it in case it crashed, but it seems after certain time it just won't do anything, like it *hung up* on the `time.sleep()`.